# xml parsing in php webservice

Tags: php, xml

i have write php web service using xml parsing but it displays

```
  error on line 3 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
```

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

my code is

```
<?php
header("Content-type:text/xml");
require 'dbconnect.php';
$query="SELECT * FROM `tbl_quiz_question` where QuestionType='$questiontype'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
if($result)
{
$xml_output ="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
$xml_output .= "<questions>\n";
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
if($row[7]!= null)
{
$path="http://localhost/Quiz/images/".$row[7];
}
else
{
$path="";
}
}
}
$xml_output .= "</questions>\n";
echo $xml_output;
?>
```

Comment: Can you post the source of the generated XML from the client side please?

Comment: If `$result` is `false` then `</questions>`

Comment: You might be looking for [XMLWriter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I am missing something but, it seems like you are not populating `$xml_output` inside the database loop at all.

Anyway, if you plan on using your existing code, pass all your data through [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to make is suitable for XML output.

If you are willing to go a step further, use the [Document Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to generate the XML. It'll take care of everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "\n" at the end (after </questions>).

Comment: Also, you don't need any new lines ("\n") for the XML to be correct. You can have an entire XML documment in one line and stil be 100% valid. You can use the new lines only if you want the XML to look better visually for a person.

Comment: New line characters can be used inside the XML but never as the first character or the last character in the XML

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
$xml_output .= "</questions>\n";
```

To

```
$xml_output .= "</questions>";
```